# Java - regex to split till the last dot

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I am trying to split the string into 2 parts using regex. the first part should be all the digit including dots in between till the last dot. The 2nd part of the array should be the last digit excluding the dot. 
Why is this regex not giving the desired result?

```
    String str = "12.345.678.90.111.213.1";
    String[] arr  = str.split("[^\\.]([^.]*)$" , 2);
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[12.345.678.90.111.213,1]
```

**Actual Output:**

```
[12.345.678.90.111.213., ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string on the zero-width location between the last dot and the character that precedes the last dot:

```
(?=\.[^.]+$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LXbbd3/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using regex, you can do it easily using `String::substring` as shown below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "12.345.678.90.111.213.1";
        if (str.lastIndexOf(".") != -1) {
            String[] arr = { str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(".")), str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(".") + 1) };
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[12.345.678.90.111.213, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although this solution, does produce the desired result, I am looking for a regex that will help me do the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need the regex to only *match* the last dot, while insuring there are no more dot following it.

To do that you match the dot, which needs escaping, so use `\.`, then use a zero-width positive look-ahead to verify that the rest of the string doesn't have a dot, i.e. use `(?=[^.]+$)`

Alternatively, use a zero-width negative look-ahead to ensure it cannot find a dot, i.e. `(?!.*\.)`

I prefer the first, so use `\.(?=[^.]+$)`, which in Java means `"\\.(?=[^.]+$)"`

Answer (score 1):

```js
str = "12.345.678.90.111.213.1";
arrMatch = str.match(/(.*)\.(.*)/);
arr = [arrMatch[1], arrMatch[2]];
console.log(arr);
```

or

```js
str = "12.345.678.90.111.213.1";
arr = str.split(/(.*)\.(.*)/).filter(el => {
    return !!el;
})

console.log(arr);
```